# Hide tbody if number of shown tr is smaller than n

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table who looks like following

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tbody class="green">
        <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="blue">
        <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Is it possible, using jquery, to hide each tbody from the table if the number of the tr inside the tbody is lower than 2? I tiried this but it didin't worked. All the tr in the table got hidden.

```
   $('.table tbody').each(function(){ 
  if($(this).not("tr:hidden").length <2)
    {      
      $(this).parent().find("tbody").hide();
    }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find()` on `this` object to find the length of all `tr`

```
$(this).find("tr").length
```

Then you can use `this` to target the specific `tbody` element to hide.

**Please Note:** nested `tbody` (`tbody` inside `tbody`) is not valid.

**Demo:**

```js
$('table tbody').each(function(){ 
  if($(this).find("tr").length < 2){      
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody class="green">
        <tr>
            <td>First tbody Data1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="blue">
        <tr>
            <td>Second tbody Data1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Second tbody Data2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If you are using `$('table tbody').each() ` you can shorten `$(this).closest("tbody").hide();` to `$(this).hide();` as `$(this)` already targets the tbody you are looping

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with vanilla JS quite easily, just grab all the tbodys and check their children's length for the amount you want and then set display to non if it doesn't meet that threshold.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

```js
const tbodys = document.querySelectorAll('tbody')

Array.from(tbodys).forEach(tbody => {
  const { children } = tbody;
  const threshold = children.length < 2;

  tbody.style.display = threshold ? 'none' : '';
})
```

```css
.blue {background-color: blue}
.green {background-color: green}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tbody class="green">
        <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="blue">
        <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

But if you want to just Jquery

```js
$('table tbody').each(function() {
  if (this.children.length < 2) $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
.blue {
  background-color: blue
}

.green {
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tbody class="green">
      <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="blue">
      <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```